# How to alternate digits from two integers in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C for engineering school but I can't figure this problem out. Can you guys please help me?

Here is the assignment:

> Write a program that receives two integer values ​​as input
> positive; the program calculates and returns a new integer obtained by alternating the digits of the two numbers starting from the least significant. In the case a value in input has more digits than the other, the remaining digits are displayed on the left of the resulting value. Don't worry about any overflow problems.
>
> Start with the digit of the first of the two values ​​received as input.
>
> Example: given two values ​​121 and 35365, the program returns 35316251.

I tried to count the digits of the numbers, I thought that maybe I could play around with division and powers but I don't really know how to do it.

In the exercise it is stated that we can't use arrays.

PS sorry my english is really bad

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    int a,b,n1,n2,numFin,potenza;

    do {
        printf("inserire primo numero:");
        scanf("%d", &a);
    } while (a<0);
    
    do {
        printf("\ninseririre secondo numero:");
        scanf("%d", &b);
    } while (b<0);
    
    for (n1=1; a<1; n1++) {
        a = a / n1*10;
    }
    for (n2=1; b<1; n2++) {
        b = b / n2*10;
    }
```

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right; I was wrong. How's that for a "binary" delineation? `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

You need something like the following steps:

```
Set a sum = 0
Set a factor = 1
while either of the numbers is not zero
    if the first number is no zero
        get the remainder by dividing by 10
        multiply the remainder by the factor
        add the remainder to the sum
        divide the number by 10
        multiply the factor by 10
    if the second number is not zero
        repeat the same steps as above
print the sum
```

Comment: @Verbatim I deliberately did not mention that, something for the questioner to discover. Oh, and thanks for the vote if that was you.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment which pointed out the (deliberate) typo. Yes, 1 upvote for the excellent pseudocode.